# How to fetch text from single cell excel sheet published on Microsoft OneDrive?

Tags: php, curl, onedrive

Below link displays a single cell value (1,250.21) from a Microsoft Excel sheet hosted at my OneDrive:

https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=1675CEC70987A1BC&resid=1675CEC70987A1BC%217430&authkey=ADt10TUFiPzFu90&em=2&wdAllowInteractivity=False&Item=%27AC-QR%27!K1&wdHideGridlines=True

or

http://goo.gl/FXbaMF

Now, I tries fetching this URL via standard cUrl, but got a lot of JavaScript & standard HTML only, nowhere on the whole page there was this value mentioned.

Is there any way to fetch this value(1,250.21)?

Comment: You might need to use a library like PHP-ExcelReader to parse the Excel doc.
A quick break down might look like ... 
curl back the Excel doc at the above address
then use the PHP Excel parser to grab the value

Comment: @b_dubb Yes, that would be last resort, but my curiosity is that how come Chrome displays this value, but does not show in Source Code of the web page.

Comment: you seem like a nice enough fellow but no way am I clicking on that link

Comment: @b_dubb :) Trust me, it just displays a Microsoft Online Excel iFrame & a single cell containing 1,400.21

Answer (score 1):

Fetching this URL using cURL gives a different result from getting it through the browser, maybe the site checks for some cookie , session variable or even the user agent to determine if it's an automated request. Maybe you'll have to add some extra param to your cURL request in order to get the whole document. Take a look at [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Once you've done that, you'll simply have to parse the document and find this element:

I guess you'll have to parse the HTML fetched by cURL and look for this element which holds the value you want:

```
<div originalhorizontalalignment="3" class="cv-nwr" style="width:66px;max-height:16px;text-align:right;font:bold 10pt Calibri,'Segoe UI',Thonburi,Arial,Verdana,Sans-Serif;" title="1,250.21">1,250.21</div>
```

Comment: Did you get this via cUrl @ PHP/Apache server? I have not setup a proper PHP cUrl on a server for this yet, but  OnlinecUrl.com output at http://codepad.org/HLd7Cph0 does not contain "div" in it. Even the chrome does not give options to see the source code of "iFrame". Thanks..

Comment: I mean how did you get this text?

Comment: Sorry, I tried that browser, but I noted that using cUrl the result is different. Maybe the site checks for some cookie , session variable or even the user agent to determine if it's an automated request.

Comment: Thanks, I did some digging around in Chrome>Dev Tools>Elements, & found this by **Inspect this element**:`<div originalhorizontalalignment="3" class="cv-nwr" style="width:66px;max-height:16px;text-align:right;font:bold 10pt Calibri,'Segoe UI',Thonburi,Arial,Verdana,Sans-Serif;" title="1,250.21">1,250.21</div>` Will do more digging tomorrow as now its mid-night.. Thanks :)

Comment: Exactly! Ok, let us know if you make some progress.

Comment: Ok, I found that the URL I have is loading an iFrame inside it, which cUrl can not get (browser gets it after loading the page).

Comment: Oh I see..so have you found a solution for this?

Comment: No.. have almost given up.. Onedrive iframe uses a html form with mesh of hidden input values & scripts ( & POSTs it to embed.aspx), which then reply with simple CSS & data required to render the Excel sheet. To capture this, I need to go deeper with Javascript/DOM/Ajax. In the intial tests, I found that OneDrive changes the div ID every time to a random string. So, almost abandoned :(.